# ClearAll required twice on a symbol with SyntaxInformation

Tags: bugs, syntax-highlighting, clear

```
SyntaxInformation[f] = {"ArgumentsPattern" -> {}};
f[] := 0;
```

After one `ClearAll[f]` or `` ClearAll["`*"] ``, `f` remains black. It takes two to turn `f` blue, and it can't be in the same cell: just running `ClearAll[f];ClearAll[f]` is not enough. Yet one `ClearAll` is enough to clear `FullDefinition[f]`.

In fact, the line `f[] := 0;` is extraneous; all that's needed is to define `SyntaxInformation[f]`.

Is this a bug? Is there anything I can run once to turn everything blue?

Comment: Seems like a bug to me. I didn't look into this too much, but it looks like the front-end is informed about the symbol removal before the syntax-information stuff is updated. This probably confuses the front-end abojt the status of the symbol. As a workaround, clearing the syntax-information before clearing the symbol works for me: `SyntaxInformation[f]=.; ClearAll[f]`

Comment: @LukasLang Can I enter something to clear all syntax information I've defined before a ``ClearAll["`*"]``?

Comment: Something like ``Quiet[Unset@*SyntaxInformation@*Symbol /@ Names["`*"]]``  should do the job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug. From Wolfram Technical Support: "I have reproduced the issue and have reported it to our developers."

Workaround, from the comments by Lukas Lang: `SyntaxInformation[f]=.; ClearAll[f]` or `` Quiet[Unset@*SyntaxInformation@*Symbol /@ Names["`*"]]; ClearAll["`*"] ``.